# What is the equivalent of India's Form 16 in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, india, paperwork

I need to submit my last three years Form 16 (related to income tax returns) to apply for US visa.

But I was in UK for  more than a year in last three years span.

So I do have Form 16 for the year 2014 and 2016 but not 2015. What equivalent document from UK can I produce?

Comment: Did you file a tax return/pay income tax in the UK in 2015?

Comment: @RedBaron Yes I did

Comment: Ask for SA-302 from HMRC.

Comment: I guess `Form-16` equivalent in UK is `P60`.